# Application.Resource inline code to find

Tags: wpf

All,
I am trying to create a Metro Window Style. I have the style in Application.Resource file. I am trying to enable Dragging of the window in inline code. The problem is, when I have the style inside the Window XAML itself, I can access the properties of the Window. But in Application.Resource file, I loose the reference to the Window.

What I want to know is: how can I access the Window properties in inline code to which the style is applied to so I can apply the DragMove to the Window?

If this is not the right way then can I get the correct way of handling this problem please?

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MetroWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="6" CaptionHeight="0" GlassFrameThickness="0" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Background="#FFEEEEEE" BorderBrush="#FFA4A4A4" BorderThickness="1">
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" Height="30" Background="#FFE6E6E6" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="HeaderBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown">

                                </Border>
                                <AdornerDecorator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <x:Code>
            <![CDATA[

            private void HeaderBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                DragMove();  //////Complains here because I don't have access to the Window to which this style is applied to
            }

            ]]>
        </x:Code>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an attached behaviour.

```
public class DraggableWindowBehaviour : Behavior<Window>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += _associatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void _associatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.DragMove();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= _associatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }
}
```

Inside the Border control of your window control template:

```
<e:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:DraggableWindowBehaviour/>
</e:Interaction.Behaviors>
```